# Do closed sets with full projections intersect?

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ and $Y$ be compact, connected and metric spaces (continuum), $p_X\colon X\times Y\to X$ the projection in $X$ and $p_Y\colon X\times Y\to Y$ the projection in $Y$. Suppose that $K$ and $L$ are subcontinua of $X\times Y$ such that the following conditions holds:

- $p_X(K)=p_X(L)=X$,
- $p_Y(K)=p_Y(L)=Y$.

That is, $K$ and $L$ have full projections. Is it true that $K\cap L\neq \varnothing$?

Comment: By 'subcontinua' do you perhaps mean *closed subspace*?

Comment: I mean closed and connected subspace

Comment: Ah, yes, makes sense. And.. what are your thoughts? What's your guess?

Comment: It's difficult trying to visualize subsets of a product, but thinking on the easy ones on easy spaces like [0,1]x[0,1] it seems true.

Answer (score 1):

This is not true, eg consider the threads on a screw. More specifically if $X=[0,1]$, and $Y=S^1$, the subspaces $X_1$ and $X_2$ given by

$$X_1=\left\{\left(t,e^{2\pi it}\right):0\leq t\leq 1\right\}$$
$$X_2=\left\{\left(t,e^{2\pi i(t+0.5)}\right):0\leq t\leq 1\right\}$$
both have full projections and are closed and connected, but do not intersect.